# Am I experiencing a hardware or software issue?

Tags: networking, router

I have 3 computers in my network connected to the same router.

Computer A - my desktop computer
Computer B - Web server
Computer C - Mail server and SQL server

Everything is set up correctly externally which means I can telnet to IMAP port (143) on Computer C and Web server port (80) on Computer B.

But suddenly, in like a 10 minute interval or more often I cannot telnet to Computer C from the outside. I can telnet from Computer A and B. And I can telnet from Computer A to B from the outside.

I do not think the problem is the router. Computer C is new with Windows 2012 and I guess it is either a network problem, configuration etc on that computer. Do you have any more ideas of how to test this or?

Comment: It is possible your ISP is blocking your mail server when it detects it.

Comment: No, I have mail server on Server B. And it works with same ports. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Got windows update recently? Some windows update may change your firewall rules... (on computer C).

Comment: Thanks for your feedback - found the reason - the switch got the same ip as the computer C.

Answer (score 0):

Found out the reason. The switch and the computer accidently got the same IP :(

Thank you all for your feedback!